# Confusions about new GoogleCloudMessaging API (not the old one)

Tags: php, android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

i have followed the tutorial for GCM available at the official site:

```
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html
```

and i have successfully implemented it on my app.. but as i am new on android i have few confusions about GCM i would really appriciate if someone could clear these points.

- i wrote a PHP script(found from google) and hardcoded my regisration ID (just for testing) when i run the script i recieve a notification on my device.. but i dont wanna receive a notification rather i want to silently recieve the data and handle it on my device. is it possible?? here is the PHP code:

  ```
  $regID=$_REQUEST['regID'];
  $registatoin_ids=array($regID);
  $msg=array("message"=>'HI Wasif');
  $url='https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
  $fields=array
   (
    'registration_ids'=>$registatoin_ids,
    'data'=>$msg
   );
  $headers=array
   (
    'Authorization: key=MY-REG-KEY',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
   );
  $ch=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($fields));
  $result=curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo $result;
  ```
- Second point is i want to customize the notification i receive on my device i receive a notification like this...(see picture below) but i want to replace the heading text "GCM Notification" with my app's name and the message should me displayed properly(not like the key,value text) and also change the image of notification... can anybody plz provide a tutorial how to do it in new GoogleCloudMessaging API?? (please dont provide old methods if it is not same for new GoogleCouldMessaging API)
  [image]

  BROADCAST RECEIVER CODE:
      public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

  ```
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
      ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
              GcmIntentService.class.getName());
      // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
      startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
      setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: please show us your BroadCastReciever for gcm. There should be the Notificationbuilder.

Comment: please see above i have added BroadCastReciever code

Comment: @A.S. thanks brother u gave me a hint and i did it! i have customized the notification inside GCMIntentService.java thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this link helps : [GCM](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

1) If you don't want to receive notification on device then remove the code of Notification    from GCMIntentService class under generateNotification() method.

2) You can provide your app name, app icon by implementing following code in generateNotification() method :

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

}
```

Hope this helps.